# Excel: formula is not updated when I paste into a new row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac. I put the following formula into a cell:

=IF($E2<30,1,IF($E2<60,2,IF($E2<90,3,IF($E2<120,4,5))))

It's basic classifier. Now, I want to use the same formula in every row of my spreadsheet. How do I do it? I expected Excel to be smart and change row number when I paste the formula into the new cell, however, it's not happening.

Comment: Are you copying the formula in the formula bar or the cell itself? if the former, it won't work, if the latter, it should.

Comment: Click on the cell with the formula in it, then scroll to the bottom cell where you want the formula to be. Press "CTRL" and the down arrow, then press "CTRL + D"

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, you're right. User error - i was selecting text and not the cell. Thanks, you should promote the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a formula to populate correctly along a column or row, the cell containing the formula must be selected and copied. If you try to copy the formula from the formula bar, the exact string will copy and not update for varying rows/columns)